# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi form sea circular y se vea bien?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi formulario sea circular y que los bordes se vean bien y no despixelados. Este es el resultado de lo que he logrado hasta ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, este es el código en c#:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    pictureBox1.Top = 0;
    pictureBox1.Left = 0;
    Top = 0;
    Left = Screen.AllScreens.First().Bounds.Width - pictureBox1.Width;
    path.AddEllipse(pictureBox1.Bounds);            
    Region region = new Region(path);
    this.Region = region;
}
```

Tambien he intentado ponerle como fondo al formulario un color y establecer el TransparenceKey a ese color, pero sale bastante parecido inclusive le añade algunos restos de ese color de fondo al borde.

Comment: Que color usaste en el TransparenceKey? No será que la imagen tiene justo algunos pixeles en ese exacto color?

Comment: He hecho varias pruebas y con el color que le ponga el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: No conozco cómo funciona el tema gráfico en c#, pero haciendo una pequeña investigación, me topé con esto: [Graphics.SmoothingMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) ¿La conoces? Yo lo probé con tu código, y pues, si bien queda algo pixelado, en teoría es la forma de suavizar los bordes de los gráficos 2D en c#... o no?

Comment: Esa propiedad esta muy bien cuando estoy trabajando con graphics o sea si lo ke hiciera fuera dibujar esta perfecta pero para resolver mi problema no. Ya que despues que dibuje mi circulo con la imagen adentro y el borde este bien, como haria para hacer desaparecer todo lo que no esté en esa area. Solo conozco 2 maneras y ninguna de las 2 funcionan.

Comment: Voy a publicar una respuesta con el código que yo ejecuté, y que me genera este formulario "troquelado". No digo que será la respuesta correcta, pero tal vez te ayude a buscar la guía correcta.

Answer (score 3):

Como dije en los comentarios de tu pregunta, transcribo aquí el código de lo que yo probé, al usar la propiedad `SmoothingMode` de `Graphics`:

Este sería el Form1: El recuadro punteadito es un `PictureBox`, sin `Image` asignado. Los otros controles están encima de él, por lo tanto, son accesibles.

[image: Form1 en tiempo de diseño:]

Este sería el código fuente: si te fijas, las acciones se realizan en el evento `Paint`,  y no en el `Load`, ambos del `Form`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void ShowPensAndSmoothingMode(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            // Set the SmoothingMode property to smooth the line.
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            pictureBox1.Top = 0;
            pictureBox1.Left = 0;
            Top = 0;
            Left = Screen.AllScreens.First().Bounds.Width - pictureBox1.Width;
            path.AddEllipse(pictureBox1.Bounds);
            Region region = new Region(path);
            this.Region = region;

        }
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowPensAndSmoothingMode(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Y esto es lo que me muestra, controles totalmente funcionales:

[image: Form1 en ejecución]

(Salvo, claro, que no muestra los botones de control de ventana, pero esos se pueden emular mediante buttons y eventos...)

Ejemplo basado en la documentación oficial de [Graphics.SmoothingMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode(v=vs.110).aspx).